# Android - Why is my app crashing on setContentView

Tags: android

I tried to create a settings activity (I don't understand using a Fragment on just a single page settings) but then suddenly my setContentView on the mainactivity suddenly crashes. I tried cleaning and rebuilding but it doesn't work.

**Oncreate**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#E8EAF6"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/goal_now_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/current_calorie_text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="/"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/goal_set_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/goal_calorie_text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/goal_text_view"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**logcat**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter,
>   PID: 10880 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo
>   {com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter/com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface  method
>   'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.DecorContentParent.setWindowCallback(android.view.Window$Callback)'
>   on a null object reference
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused
>   by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.DecorContentParent.setWindowCallback(android.view.Window$Callback)'
>   on a null object reference
>
> at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:399)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>   at
>   com.leviebora.simplecaloriecounter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I also tried using an activity level attribute as style but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Could you post your MainActivity.java file?

Comment: just focus on this... and you will find your answer.---  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.support.v7.widget.DecorContentParent.setWindowCallback(android.view.Window$Callback)' on a null object reference

Comment: Posted my mainactivity